# Как объявить общий ChromiumDriver с ChromiumOptions?

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium

Как объявить общий `ChromiumDriver` с `ChromiumOptions`?

Пытался сделать так:

```
public Form1()
{
    //...
    options.AddArgument("headless");    
}

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
//...
```

Но пишет ошибку:    `CS0236 Инициализатор поля не может обращаться к нестатическому полю, методу или свойству "Form1.options".`

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: Да, спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать это всё например в конструкторе формы

```cs
private readonly ChromeDriver driver;

public Form1()
{
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.AddArgument("headless"); 
   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
}
```